# "NonNull if the function returns non-null"?

Tags: java, checker-framework

Consider a method such as `ConcurrentHashMap`'s `compute` method:

```
public V compute(
             K key,
             BiFunction<? super K,? super V,? extends V>  remappingFunction)
```

I would like to annotate this for nullability checking with checker framework:

```
public @Nullable V compute(
             K key,
             BiFunction<? super K, ? super @Nullable V, ? extends @Nullable V> remappingFunction);
```

but this isn't quite right: I would like to be able to infer that it returns `? extends @NonNull V` in order to avoid a null check in the case where I know the `remappingFunction` never returns `null`, e.g.:

```
@NonNull V value = map.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
    if (v == null) {
        return new V();
    }
    v.increment();
    return v;
});
```

Is it possible to express that?

Comment: Can you use [`@PolyNull`](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#qualifier-polymorphism) in all the places you wrote `@Nullable` in your example annotation?

Comment: @mernst that certainly seems to do the trick for tests that started failing when I added the Nullable. I'll just try running it again over everything.

Comment: @mernst yep, that's what I needed. Thanks. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) provides two ways to write conditional specifications, where a type depends on other values or types.

- [`@PolyNull`](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#qualifier-polymorphism) indicates that two types must be the same, but their common type could be either `@NonNull` or `@Nullable`.  It looks like this will enable you to express the desired specification.
- [`@EnsuresNonNullIf`](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#conditional-nullness) makes a type depend on a method's return value.

Both of these are described in section [Nullness Annotations](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-annotations) in the [Checker Framework Manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/).

PS: Once you have an improved specification, you can submit it as a pull request to update the annotated JDK that is shipped with the Checker Framework.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I will send you a pull request. Out of interest, is there any tooling for telling me when a marked-up class and stub both exist? (And if they have differing annotations, perhaps)

Comment: Per section [Using a stub file](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#stub-using) of the manual, "Use the `-AstubWarnIfOverwritesBytecode` command-line option to get a warning whenever a stub file overwrites bytecode annotations."

Comment: [Pull request](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/pull/2078).

Comment: Can I just clarify when that flag is meant to cause warnings? Looking at the master branch on github, [the only reference to it](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/2da4078f0e47b7a7d73007e17ed8cf15ae31e85e/framework/src/main/java/org/checkerframework/framework/stub/StubParser.java#L758) (or, the variable set from it) seems to be in an `if (false)` block.